# Custom Django RSS not working

Tags: django, rss

I'm a noob, so please excuse me if this is a silly request. I am trying to create custom RSS feeds for each category of a website, but somehow I can't manage to pass the parameter (a category slug) in order to properly build the requested feed. The RSS should be located at an address like this: http://www.website.com/category-name/feed

Here's what I have:

In urls.py:

```
from project.feeds import FeedForCategory
urlpatterns = patterns('category.views',
 #...
 url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/feed/?$', FeedForCategory),
)
```

In feeds.py:

```
from django.contrib.syndication.feeds import Feed

class FeedForCategory(Feed):

  def get_object(self, request, category_slug):
    return get_object_or_404(Category, slug_name=category_slug)

  def title(self, obj):
    return "website.com - latest stuff"

  def link(self, obj):
    return "/articles/"

  def description(self, obj):
    return "The latest stuff from Website.com"

  def get_absolute_url(self, obj):
    return settings.SITE_ADDRESS + "/articles/%s/" % obj.slug_name

  def items(self, obj):
    return Article.objects.filter(category=category_slug)[:10]
```

The error that I get is: "_ *init* _() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category_slug'", but the traceback isn't helpful, it only shows some base python stuff.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/

You need to pass an instance of the feed object to your url patterns. So do this in urls.py:

```
from project.feeds import FeedForCategory
urlpatterns = patterns('category.views',
 #...
url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/feed/?$', FeedForCategory()),
)
```

Comment: Okay, but if I do this, then I get:
"__init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)"

Comment: Ah, you are also using the deprecated Feed class. Use `from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed` not `from django.contrib.syndication.feeds import Feed`